# ASP.NET identity async vs sync issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Why there is async and sync versions of UserManagerExtensions (like CreateLocalUser and CreateLocalUserAsync) but only async methods on RoleManagerExtensions? How I suppose to add user to a role from my legacy code? There is only AddUserToRoleAsync and I have a deadlock when running it synchronously. AddUserToRoleAsync(userId, role).Result hangs and .ConfigureAwait(false) does nothing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the RTM release, there will be sync versions, I'm guessing this was just a bug in the RC release.

Here's what code we use internally to implement the sync versions, you can use this in the meantime to safely call the async methods:

```
static class AsyncHelper {
    private static readonly TaskFactory _myTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) {
        return _myTaskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func) {
        _myTaskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```